# Designing UI for android and iOS application

Tags: android, ios, user-interface

I'm designing user interface for an app that is gonna have versions for both android and iOS (I'm gonna design two interfaces, one for android and one for iOS), but I don't know what ratio should I use for my screen height and width regarding so many different devices that support android or iOS!
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Android - see [here](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html).

For iOS - see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](http://www.onbile.com/info/mobile-screen-sizes/), the most dominant screen size is 240 x 320 or QVGA.

Also, [this site](http://speckyboy.com/2011/11/28/creating-pixel-perfect-ui-for-iphone-applications/) states that 512×512 is the universal size for apps.